# SQL запрос, выбирающий записи по максимальному значению

Tags: sql, oracle

Какой запрос будет работать наиболее корректно если нужно выбрать записи с максимальным значением `column1(timestamp)`, где `column2(varchar)='value'`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table_name 
WHERE column1=(SELECT MAX(column1) FROM table_name WHERE column2='value') 
AND   column2='value';
```

Вариант с подзапросом не очень хорошая идея.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM  table_name
WHERE column2='value'
ORDER BY column1 DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

Comment: А через агрегатную функцию MAX можно сделать?

Comment: @user212179 max() подразумевает подзапрос. Если надо получить пару колонок - то еще куда не шло, варианты есть. но когда всю запись целиком, то красиво, начиная с Oracle 12 так как в этом ответе. На более ранних версиях примерно то же можно изобразить с rownum

Comment: @user212179 *А через агрегатную функцию MAX можно сделать?* Сделать можно всё. Но можно полюбопытствовать, зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Через `HAVING` пробовали?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  column2='value' 
HAVING column1 = MAX(column1)
```

**UPD:**
  В Oracle sql так писать нельзя.

Comment: Мне известна только одна СУБД, где возможен такой синтаксис (использование не группированной колонки в having) - это SQLite. **В Oracle так невозможно**

Comment: Проверил, к сожалению это так